# How do I make an animation not reset the position of the object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to make an animation in which the object at hand moves to the right a certain amount. However I discovered that if I animate the object at -3 and make it move to -1.5, whenever the animation is executed, the object flies back to -3 and goes to -1.5, instead of moving 1.5 units to the right (that's probably how it's supposed to work). How do I make an object move 1.5 units to the right using the Unity animation system, regardless of current position?

Comment: Does the object have a navmesh agent on? do you have any code that would make it move other than the animation?

Comment: Well, I have one that uses Lerp, but it is too limited and impractical for what I'm planning on doing. Oh and no navmesh.

Comment: Maybe [Root Motion](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html) would help?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to make animation do "relative" motions is to attach your object to a parent object. This way the object animates relative to its parent's transform.